# Cin getting skipped after being used in for loop

Tags: c++, cin

Just wrote 3-4 lines to reproduce the problem. After using `cin >>` inside a "for loop" to repeatedly take input, all the next `cin >> (s)` always get skipped.

Anything/Everything other than `cin` works fine.(just want to know why this happens and what shall I do to be able to use `cin` further in the program)

```
for(int x;cin >> x;){
        cout << x <<endl;
}
int a;
cin >>a;
```

No error message.

Comment: How are you ending the loop?  Are you sending ctrl+c/ctrl+z to the console?

Comment: Or perhaps `Ctrl-D` (on Linux or macOS)?

Comment: Have you looked into cin.ignore() and cin.clear() to try and ditch the ^D that's stuck in your cin buffer?

Comment: My loop ends on entering any character other than an integer. I am unsure of what that amounts to in terms of how it ends the loop.
P.S. - I use codeblocks(just in case if that is relevant)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whatever you're doing to make `cin >> x` fail (to break the loop) will just affect `cin >> a` too, as it's the same dang command!

The object `cin` doesn't "know" about your loop logic, and neither does your operating system/terminal, neither could it in general know that you intended for some sort of "reset" to happen once the loop was broken. You'd have to signal that yourself. However, it's likely you can't just patch that in because:

- If you hit Ctrl+C to end the program, then the program has ended.
- If you hit Ctrl+D (Linux/macOS) or Ctrl+Z (Windows), then you gave the stream the "end of file" condition and it won't accept any more. The `std::cin` object will have the EOF flag set on it, and this persists. (Sometimes you can clear this manually but I wouldn't recommend doing so, as you can get into confusion on the sending side, depending on your platform…)

You will have to find another way to break your loop, either with some "magic reserved number", by having a more sophisticated input protocol, by only reading some number *n* of initial inputs, or some other means that depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks. I get the end of file condition now, I guess I'll come back to this in a little while after I have a better understanding of the I/o stream.

Answer (score 0):

The second expression in the `for` header is the loop condition; the loop will continue running as long as this is true. Your condition is always true, so the loop is never exited.

You could add some code inside your loop to exit it, e.g. `if (x == 0) break;`

However, I would suggest redesigning the loop. Your loop condition is very unusual, and will give most people a bit of head-scratching before they figure out what's going on. Perhaps you can put the reading operation inside the loop body?

**How `>>` works**

For `std::basic_istream` (`std::cin` is one of these), the `>>` operator is overridden to implement formatted data extraction, and it's designed to be chainable (e.g. `cin >> a >> b >> c`). This works because:

1. `>>` is left-associative, so it groups as `((cin >> a) >> b) >> c)`
2. `>>` returns a reference to the stream object, so you can keep adding more `>>` as much as you like.

Also, a `std::basic_istream` can be converted to `bool`, and will be `true` as long as no error has occurred. Thus, your loop condition is always `cin`, and since you're presumably not getting errors, is always true.

Comment: Using `cin >> x` in a loop condition is a common way of reading until the end of the input stream, and is, in fact, the correct way of doing so compared to `while (!cin.eof())`. When using this you would end the stream using something like Ctrl + Z, which in this case prevents the read operation after the loop from working correctly.